# SQL Select with grouping and replacing a column

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a requirement in which I need to retrieve rows in a select query in which I have to get value of END_DATE as EFFECTIVE_DATE -1 DAY for the records with same key (CARD_NBR in this case)
I have tried using it by GROUP by but I am not able to get the desired output. Could someone please help in guiding me ? The record with most recent effective date should have END_DATE as 9999-12-31 only.

Table:

| CARD_NBR | SERIEL_NO | EFFECTIVE_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-01-25 | 9999-12-31 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-02-15 | 9999-12-31 |
| 67899 | 1 | 2021-03-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| 67899 | 2 | 2021-04-02 | 9999-12-31 |
| 67899 | 3 | 2021-05-24 | 9999-12-31 |

Output:

| CARD_NBR | SERIEL_NO | EFFECTIVE_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-24 |
| 12345 | 2 | 2021-01-25 | 2021-02-14 |
| 12345 | 3 | 2021-02-15 | 9999-12-31 |
| 67899 | 1 | 2021-03-01 | 2021-04-01 |
| 67899 | 2 | 2021-04-02 | 2021-05-24 |
| 67899 | 3 | 2021-05-24 | 9999-12-31 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(effective_date - interval '1 day', 1, effective_date) over (partition by card_nbr order by effective_date) as imputed_end_date
from t;
```

Date manipulations are highly database-dependent so this uses Standard SQL syntax.  You can incorporate this into an `update`, but the best approach also depends on the database.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this on SQLite v3.20.1 tutorial point SQL executor but its not working

Comment: /* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE BANK(CARD integer , SERIEL INTEGER , EFFECTIVE DATE,END DATE);

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO BANK VALUES(12,1,'2021-01-01','9999-12-31');
INSERT INTO BANK VALUES(12,2,'2021-02-02','9999-12-31');
INSERT INTO BANK VALUES(12,3,'2021-03-24','9999-12-31');
INSERT INTO BANK VALUES(33,1,'2021-01-05','9999-12-31');
INSERT INTO BANK VALUES(33,2,'2021-05-04','9999-12-31');
COMMIT;

Comment: @ShubhamSharma . . . "not working" is a useless description.  Does it produce an error?  Results that you don't think are correct?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite v.3.25 now supports windows function and you can use below code to get your result.

```
SELECT A.CARD_NBR, 
A.SRL_NO, 
A.START_DT,
COALESCE(B.START_DT,A.END_DT) AS END_DT
FROM
(
  SELECT A.CARD_NBR, 
  A.SRL_NO, 
  A.START_DT,
  A.END_DT,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.CARD_NBR ORDER BY A.SRL_NO ASC) RNUM1
  FROM T1 A
  )A
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT B.CARD_NBR, 
  B.SRL_NO, 
  B.START_DT,
  B.END_DT,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.CARD_NBR ORDER BY B.SRL_NO ASC) RNUM1
  FROM T1 B
  )B
ON A.CARD_NBR=B.CARD_NBR
AND A.RNUM1+1=B.RNUM1
```